# Fighting a Zero Suit Samus CPU in Brawl

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

For those unfamiliar with the game, to select Zero Suit Samus you have to choose (normal) Samus as your character, and then hold down certain buttons when someone presses start. (For example, with the Gamecube controller, holding down the L and R shoulder buttons works.) Now that's all well and good, but what am I supposed to do if I want to fight a CPU Zero Suit Samus? Is there an easy way to force a CPU to be Zero suit samus, or will I have to seek out a human opponent to practice that particular matchup?

Comment: I know of a way, but it involves jailbreaking your wii and a homebrew mod to SSBB. Not sure if that's what you're looking for. Hopefully, there's an easier, less legally gray method.

Comment: Nope, I'm hoping for a non-modded solution here.

Comment: Maybe if you could somehow take advantage of the AI learning and teach Zero Suit Samus to do the Up/Down/Up taunt sequence, but I don't think that'll work.

Comment: I'm assuming here that you play with items off, since otherwise it would be a simple matter to make a CPU pick up a smash ball.

Comment: Yeah, I play with items off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selecting a CPU ZSS uses the same method as a human one: Hold down specific buttons while pressing Start on the character selection screen. The key is that you need to use whatever controller is attached to the CPU player's slot.

So, with CPU Samus as P2, use the P2 controller to hold down the specific button, and you should see ZSS's head on the stage selection screen.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Training Mode and the Up/Down/Up taunt sequence to do it.

1. Start training mode, selecting Samus as your opponent.
2. Set CPU to control.
3. Pick up player two's controller and *very* quickly perform an up taunt, down taunt, and up taunt. This will cause Samus to lose her suit. (If this is difficult, slow down time to do it)

   Edit: Or you can just spawn a smash ball and use it (I can't believe I didn't think of this).
4. Set CPU to attack and battle normally.

Comment: If I was going to do training mode, it'd be easier just to spawn a smash ball and use Samus's final smash, I can never get the up/down/up taunt sequence to work.

Comment: That never occurred to me that you could spawn items in training mode. Must have slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using [Pity Final Smashes](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Pity_Final_Smash#Pity_Final_Smash):

1. Set item frequency to Off, but leave the Smash Ball item on.
2. Start a timed match with infinite time against a Samus CPU. (Alternately, start a stock match with around ten or more stocks.)
3. KO Samus a few times without losing a stock yourself. You need at least a five point lead.
4. At this point, since you are so far ahead, the game will give Samus a Pity Final Smash. Get the CPU to use the final smash and turn into Zero Suit Samus.
5. Commit suicide a few times so that you no longer have a large lead. This will keep the CPU from getting another Pity Smash.
6. Continue battling as normal. If you get too far ahead of the CPU, commit suicide a few times. (It might be helpful to turn score display on, so you can see how far ahead you are.)